# MS Access search textbox content and show in a listbox

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-forms

I have two tables named ProductTypes and Products, and also a form for each of these tables. I want to be able to search for a product type in a textbox and show in a listbox all the products related to that product type. What's the best way to do it? I tried to use Dlookup but it seems to not work properly. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Dlookup will not return a useable list of records. You need to return a recordset.

I would have a look at this search form http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html
by Allen Browne to give you some ideas of how and what you can achieve with different search and display options.

Comment: I don't really need a usabe list of records, I just need to show all the records that match the criteria in the textbox. Do you have any ideas on how to do it? Thank you!

Comment: To show all records that meet your criteria is exactly that: a list of records. You have a table of records - you want a subset of those records from that table, this **is** a recordset. You can then either apply a filter to a list of all records, or much more efficiently simply retrieve only the records that match your criteria. Either way the various methods shown in that example are going to get you where you want to go.